# SQL, Databases, Joining two tables, get average

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables one called Hotels and one called Ratings. I want to display the hotel names and then get the average rating for each hotel and display this. In the ratings table I might have 5 different ratings of a hotel so I want the average number and then display this. How would my query have to look like ?

Comment: Can you post your tables schema?

Comment: And what have you tried till now ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide details but I assume you have a primary key in Hotels which is a foreign key in Ratings (`HotelId`). You didn't specify your RDBMS but each one should have a function to average and the query will look like:

```
select h.HotelId, avg(r.Rating)
from Hotels h
inner join Ratings r on h.HotelId = r.HotelId
group by h.HotelId
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing more information. Yes your assumptions are correct and I have tried what you suggest already but I keep getting an error when trying to build such a query.

Comment: I get the error: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "Hotel_ID" as part of an aggregate function @Szymon

Comment: What's your full query?